# Osmdroid does not create folders "osmdroid" and "tiles" on device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, osmdroid

I'm trying to make something like a personal navigator using Osmdroid.
Everything was fine and worked from zip files of maps that I got from MOBAC.
But one fine morning. I cleared the application cache on the emulator and from that moment the application stopped reading local cards in the device storage and does not create the "Osmdroid" and "Cache" folders. Perhaps someone has come across this problem and can help solve it.

All permissions are in the manifest.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the library. You simply need to use Android's new storage access methods. Using static permissions like this will not suffice.

Comment: If your default OsmDroid cache location is in the app's private folder (which is recommended), clearing the cache will delete the app's private folder. You must verify that your default OsmDroid cache location has been recreated (create it if not) following the app cache reset when the app starts.